# Jquery not getting loaded properly in Electron ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I am running a project with angular, electron and bootstrap.

I created a dropdown item like this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
<li class="nav-item dropdown">

        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Accounts</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add Members</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">View Memebers</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Remove Members</a>
        </div>


    </li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

This works if I open localhost:4000.

However when i run it on electron it just doesnt work.

I also get an error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at scripts.bundle.js:15
    at scripts.bundle.js:15
    at scripts.bundle.js:15
    at scripts.bundle.js:15
```

I think its related to jQuery as It doesnt come up in Chrome browser.

I have included this in angular-cli

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

Also have these libraries included in package.json

```
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"popper.js": "^1.14.2",
```

What else can i Do to make sure jQuery is loaded before bootstrap is in Electron ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <select id="resizing_select" data-ng-options="usr for usr in UsersBits" ng-model="selectedBits" ng-change="changeBits()" edit-inline="" class="btc RightSeg dropdown-coin classic">
        <!--<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Accounts</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add Members</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">View Memebers</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Remove Members</a>
        </div>-->


    </li>
 </ul>

</div>

# Below angular script #

<script>
$scope.getRate = function() {

        // Drop-Down section    
            $scope.UsersBits = ["Accounts","Add Members","View Memebers","Remove Members"];
            $scope.selectedBits = $scope.UsersBits[0];          
}   

</script>
```